# Problema con las tildes en textfield dentro de popover

Tags: javafx

Estoy usando un PopOver que contiene un TextField y se muestra cuando el usuario hace click en el imageView de un CustomTextField. Cuando tecleo dentro del TextField interno, todo va bien hasta que introduzco una vocal acentuada, que para  mi sorpresa la recoge el TextField externo en vez del interno.

Muestro imágenes de lo que sucede, cuando `popover.show(imageView)`

[image]

Cuando el popover se muestra desde un botón no hay ningún problema `popover.show(button)`

[image]

No se, parece tratarse de un bug. Si alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué sucede esto, agradecería cualquier ayuda. Gracias

EDIT: Aquí reproduzco un ejemplo de código en el que se produce el efecto que comento, cuando introduces una vocal con tilde en textfield interno, no aparece en el interno, pero sí en el externo.

```
public class PopOverTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        CustomTextField externo = new CustomTextField();
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image("test/image.png"));
        externo.setLeft(imgView);

        CustomTextField interno = new CustomTextField();

        PopOver popOver = new PopOver();
        popOver.setContentNode(interno);

        imgView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            popOver.show(imgView);

        });


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(externo);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola @axiorema. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías incluir el código dentro de la pregunta? La idea es que se pueda reproducir (siguiendo el formato descripto en [mcve]).El enlace para [edit] está bajo la pregunta.

Comment: @Mariano, gracias por tu interés, adjunto un ejemplo de código donde se reproduce el efecto que sucede en mi aplicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He encontrado una solución a este problema.

Consiste en cambiar el KeyEventDispather del TextField externo por el interno y funciona a perfectamente.

```
externo.setEventDispatcher(interno.getEventDispatcher());
```

previamente lo guardamos para poder restituirlo después:

```
EventDispatcher dispatcher = externo.getEventDispatcher();
```

Para ampliar el ejemplo para el caso en el  que haya más de un TextField interno, se debe cambiar el EventDispatcher por el de cada TextField cuando recibe el foco y restituirlo cuando lo pierde.

Muestro el ejemplo completo con dos TextFields internos:

```
public class PopOverTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        CustomTextField externo = new CustomTextField();
        ImageView imgView = new ImageView(new Image("test/image.png"));
        externo.setLeft(imgView);


        CustomTextField interno1 = new CustomTextField();
        CustomTextField interno2 = new CustomTextField();
        VBox box = new VBox(5, interno1, interno2);

        PopOver popOver = new PopOver();
        popOver.setContentNode(box);
        popOver.setArrowLocation(PopOver.ArrowLocation.TOP_LEFT);

        EventDispatcher dispatcher = externo.getEventDispatcher();

        imgView.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            popOver.show(imgView);
        });


        interno1.focusedProperty().addListener((observable,  oldValue,  newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                externo.setEventDispatcher(interno1.getEventDispatcher());
            } else {
                externo.setEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
            }
        });

        interno2.focusedProperty().addListener((observable,  oldValue,  newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                externo.setEventDispatcher(interno2.getEventDispatcher());
            } else {
                externo.setEventDispatcher(dispatcher);
            }
        });


        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(externo);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("PopOver Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```